After migrating the Docker container to Linux, images are not loading
After migrating the Docker container to Linux, images are not loading; in the browser, I receive:

GET /storage/image/WBRNZ0c6tnOfED2APNuYRcSjqIfzvJWXYnBlNRkB.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403
The docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www/
          - ./_docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        ports:
          - "8876:80"
        depends_on:
          - app
        container_name: project_nginx
      app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www/
        depends_on:
            - db
        container_name: project_app

      db:
          image: mysql:8.0
          restart: always
          volumes:
              - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
          environment:
              MYSQL_DATABASE: blogdb
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          ports:
              - "8101:3306"
          command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
          container_name: project_db
      phpmyadmin:
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
          container_name: phpmyadmin
          environment:
              PMA_HOST: db
              PMA_USER: root
              PMA_PASSWORD: root
          ports:
              - "8080:80"
          depends_on:
              - db

The nginx.conf file looks like this:
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        root /var/www/public;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            gzip_static on;
        }
    }



At first, I thought it was a permissions issue. I found information on the forum stating that Nginx does not have permissions to a certain folder, and this can be fixed with the command:

chmod 777 -R storage

However, in this case, I get: chmod: changing permissions of 'storage': Operation not permitted. Then I found that if I run it with sudo, I can grant permissions as the superuser. The command works, but the images still do not load. I dug further and checked the permissions of the folders by running the ls -l command:

drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data   4096 Nov  5 22:58 storage

The storage folder seems to have permissions for www-data (as I understand, this is typically the server's username).
If I try to directly access http://localhost:8876/storage/image/8CvZHzr5BJnZseIkh8Ne7sTMyVFHcGBUoXeAmNXS.jpg, I also get an error.
Thank you in advance; please don't be harsh, I'm just learning!

Can you start any images to get a running container? Reason I'm asking is the thought behind [mcve], i.e. that you reduce the scope of your problem so that only one possible cause remains.

Yes, my docker container is starting. I uploaded my project to github, maybe someone can help me in this way, I just don't quite understand what the error might be and just described the algorithm of my actions
https://github.com/aloelose/MyBlog.git

Please [edit] your question so it contains all relevant info.

Enter the Laravel container
First check if the storage folder link is in your public folder.
If you can't find it, run
php artisan storage:link

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/filesystem#the-public-disk
